# Outputting Fractions

Tags: python, mathematics, error-handling

This program is to return a number one at a time from a given input list of numbers, with a frequency proportional to probability/fraction associated with each number.

I know it could be made a generator function. But if I have to do it inside a class, can you please suggest improvements to this code, particularly with regards to the exception classes I have made below?

```
from random import random
from bisect import bisect_right

class Invalid_fraction(ValueError): pass
class Negative_fraction(ValueError): pass
class Sum_fraction(ValueError): pass
class NullValues(ValueError): pass

class RandomGen(object):    
    def __init__(self, nums, fractions):
        #Basic error checks
        if ( len(nums)==0 or len(fractions) == 0):
            raise NullValues("Null sample space")

        if ( len(nums) != len(fractions) ):
            raise Invalid_fraction("Invalid fraction list")

        #Data initiallisations
        self._sum  = 0
        self._fractions= []
        self._nums = nums 

    #Allocating a range within 0-1 to each of the input number, along with check for negative fraction.

        for p in fractions:
            if p < 0:
                raise Negative_fraction("negative fraction") 
            self._sum += p
            self._fractions.append(self._sum)

        if self._sum != 1:
            raise Sum_fraction("Sum of fractions is not equal to 1")

    def next_num(self):     
        #Get a random number between 0 and 1 and yield the number of the bucket
        random_number = random()
        index = bisect_right(self._fractions,random_number)
        return self._nums[index]
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview.SE! Can you give us a simple example to know how to use your code ?

Comment: r=RandomGen([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2], [0.06, 0.15, 0.53, 0.26])
c=collections.Counter((r.next_num for i in range(100)))
print(c)

This should give something like this:
{0: 55, -1: 25, 1: 19, 2: 1}

Comment: Your example does not work : a value is missing in the second list and parenthesis are required to call the function in your generator expression.

Comment: Sorry. r=RandomGen([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2], [0.06, 0.15, 0.53, 0.20,0.06])  >>> c=collections.Counter((r.next_num() for i in range(100)))
>>> print(c)
Counter({0: 55, 1: 22, -1: 10, -2: 7, 2: 6})

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, it seems unnecessary to have any custom exceptions (and if you keep them, they should all have [PEP-8-compliant names](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#exception-names)). All of the custom exceptions could just be [`ValueError`s](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError) (*"when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value"*) with different messages, e.g.:

```
if not nums or not fractions: # note empty collections evaluate False in a boolean context
    raise ValueError("Null sample space")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Style**

Your code does not respect [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

You'll find various tools to check your code and I suggest you use them.
After making a few cosmetic changes (spacing, line length, line breaks, etc), your code looks like :

```
class Invalid_fraction(ValueError):
    pass


class Negative_fraction(ValueError):
    pass


class Sum_fraction(ValueError):
    pass


class NullValues(ValueError):
    pass


class RandomGen(object):
    def __init__(self, nums, fractions):
        #Basic error checks
        if len(nums) == 0 or len(fractions) == 0:
            raise NullValues("Null sample space")

        if len(nums) != len(fractions):
            raise Invalid_fraction("Invalid fraction list")

        # Data initiallisations
        self._sum = 0
        self._fractions = []
        self._nums = nums

        # Allocating a range within 0-1 to each of the input number
        # along with check for negative fraction.
        for p in fractions:
            if p < 0:
                raise Negative_fraction("negative fraction")
            self._sum += p
            self._fractions.append(self._sum)

        if self._sum != 1:
            raise Sum_fraction("Sum of fractions is not equal to 1")

    def next_num(self):
        # Get a random number between 0 and 1 and yield the number of the bucket
        random_number = random()
        index = bisect_right(self._fractions, random_number)
        return self._nums[index]
```

Class names and and docstrings are still to be fixed bu I'll leave that to you.

**Logic**

If you check that the 2 inputs have the same length first, you don't have to check that they are both non-empty.

Also, because an empty list of fraction would lead to a sum of 0, this error would be properly caught and signalled to the user so this check might not be useful.

Once your object is properly created, we always have `self._sum == 1`, thus, there is probably no need to store it in the object.

Your code then becomes :

```
def __init__(self, nums, fractions):
    #Basic error checks
    if len(nums) != len(fractions):
        raise Invalid_fraction("Invalid fraction list")

    # Data initialisations
    sum_prob = 0
    self._fractions = []
    self._nums = nums

    # Allocating a range within 0-1 to each of the input number
    # along with check for negative fraction.
    for p in fractions:
        if p < 0:
            raise Negative_fraction("negative fraction")
        sum_prob += p
        self._fractions.append(sum_prob)

    if sum_prob != 1:
        raise Sum_fraction("Sum of fractions is not equal to 1")
```

**Responsability**

Your `RandomGen` becomes some kind of way to go through `nums`. The problem is that the list might get updated after the generator got created.
You could consider that this is an non-issue because this is not a valid way to use your class or you could try to make things differently. I can see two options for this :

- copy the list during the creation
- consider that the generator does not need to be aware of the list at all : we just generate indices and then one can use it on any container he fancies.

I prefer this second option as it would make your code simpler and also give the class a single responsibility : generating random indices.

```
class RandomGen(object):
    def __init__(self, fractions):
        # Data initialisations
        sum_prob = 0
        self._fractions = []

        # Allocating a range within 0-1 to each of the input number
        # along with check for negative fraction.
        for p in fractions:
            if p < 0:
                raise Negative_fraction("negative fraction")
            sum_prob += p
            self._fractions.append(sum_prob)

        if sum_prob != 1:
            raise Sum_fraction("Sum of fractions is not equal to 1")

    def next_num(self):
        # Get a random number between 0 and 1 and yield the number of the bucket
        random_number = random()
        return bisect_right(self._fractions, random_number)
```

**Going further**

Working with floating numbers and equal sum can be a bit awkward. Indeed, if I wanted to generate indices over `n` equal parts, I'd use an input like : `[1./n]*n`. This works fine when n is 2 or 5 but it fails when n is 3.
An easy way to make your class easier to use is to say `instead of checking if a condition is met, I'll personnally make sure the condition becomes true.`. In your case, you could divise all numbers by the sum so that the new sum becomes (roughtly) 1.

```
def __init__(self, fractions):
    sum_prob = sum(fractions)
    if sum_prob == 0:
        raise Sum_fraction("Sum is zero")

    # Allocating a range within 0-1 to each of the input number
    # along with check for negative fraction.
    self._fractions = []
    partial_sum_prob =  0
    for p in fractions:
        if p < 0:
            raise Negative_fraction("negative fraction")
        p /= sum_prob
        partial_sum_prob += p
        self._fractions.append(partial_sum_prob)
```

Comment: Many Thanks Josay for your comments. They are really useful. :)